# When creating an embedded widget, how do content-origin issues work?

Tags: javascript, html, webpack

I'm planning to make an embedded widget in js using webpack and want to be aware of any issues I may face in the process in advance as the js will hosted on an external website.

I am aware that Content-origin issues may arise - but Im not sure what applies as a content origin problem. For example, I have the embedded code:

```
<script id="widget" src="www.website.com/widget/main.js"></script>
```

And this loads the following code when the script above is added to the head

```
function build() {
 let widgetBox = document.createElement('div');
 widgetBox.setAttribute("id", "WidgetContainer");

 const ifrm = document.createElement('iframe');
 ifrm.setAttribute('id', 'WidgetFrame');

 widgetBox.appendChild(ifrm);
 return widgetBox;
};

 document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
   document.body.appendChild(build());
 });
```

Is using this in the head tag going to cause me content-origin issues as I am creating a DIV element outside of the iframe?

Or I am allowed to create as many elements as I want? But then why is the iframe needed? I see many chat widgets like zendesk and intercom use iframes. Why is that?

Comment: Your question is too broad. You might do better using StackExchange: CodeReview

Comment: @ControlAltDel Ok thank you

Comment: @ControlAltDel I will post there after the timer expires. For now I have shortened my question to be only about content-origin issues